# Trying to get a <div> to appear when I hover on another <a> element. What is my problem?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, hover

I've found answers to the problem on this site and have implemented the techniques suggested, but I really cannot see what I am missing. Is there something in the larger setup of the code that is preventing me from getting this to work or am I just blind? Is it because I already have another action taking place for hovers over `<a>`?

Relevant code is

```
.box2{
  display:none;
}

a{
border-bottom:1px dotted;
}

a:hover{
border-bottom:1px solid;
}

.topics:hover + .box2{
  display:flex;
}
```

```
<p>... interested in a <a class="topics">wide array of topics</a> ... </p>
<div class="box2">A list of topics</div>
```

https://codepen.io/brxtn/pen/KKKKzXy

```js
<!---GRAIN JAVA START--->

var viewWidth,
  viewHeight,
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx;

// change these settings
var patternSize = 64,
  patternScaleX = 1,
  patternScaleY = 1,
  patternRefreshInterval = 4,
  patternAlpha = 25; // int between 0 and 255,

var patternPixelDataLength = patternSize * patternSize * 4,
  patternCanvas,
  patternCtx,
  patternData,
  frame = 0;

window.onload = function() {
  initCanvas();
  initGrain();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};

// create a canvas which will render the grain
function initCanvas() {
  viewWidth = canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
  viewHeight = canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.scale(patternScaleX, patternScaleY);
}

// create a canvas which will be used as a pattern
function initGrain() {
  patternCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  patternCanvas.width = patternSize;
  patternCanvas.height = patternSize;
  patternCtx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');
  patternData = patternCtx.createImageData(patternSize, patternSize);
}

// put a random shade of gray into every pixel of the pattern
function update() {
  var value;

  for (var i = 0; i < patternPixelDataLength; i += 4) {
    value = (Math.random() * 255) | 0;

    patternData.data[i] = value;
    patternData.data[i + 1] = value;
    patternData.data[i + 2] = value;
    patternData.data[i + 3] = patternAlpha;
  }

  patternCtx.putImageData(patternData, 0, 0);
}

// fill the canvas using the pattern
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);

  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(patternCanvas, 'repeat');
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
}

function loop() {
  if (++frame % patternRefreshInterval === 0) {
    update();
    draw();
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

<!---GRAIN JAVA END--->



<!---LEAF JAVA START--->

let leaf = false;

const leaf_animation = () => {
  if (!leaf) {
    document.querySelector(".scale-in-hor-left").style.display = "block";
    leaf = true;
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".scale-in-hor-left").style.display = "none";
    leaf = false;
  }
}

document.querySelector("#menuleaf").addEventListener("click", leaf_animation);

<!---LEAF JAVA END--->
```

```css
body {
  background-size: 70px 70px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, grey 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, grey 1px, transparent 1px);
  font-family: Quicksand;
}

#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 80%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Quicksand;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  font-color: grey;
  font-size: 11pt;
  margin: 0px;
}

.box1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: static;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  width: 399px;
  height: 280px;
  margin-left: 62px;
  margin-top: 62px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: white;
}

.box2 {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: static;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  font-size: 9pt;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  width: 331px;
  height: 121px;
  margin-left: 69px;
  margin-top: 132px;
  padding: 9px;
  background: white;
}

.topics:hover+.box2 {
  display: flex;
}

#menuleaf {
  cursor: help;
}

#menuleaf:hover,
#menuleaf:focus {
  margin-left: 2.5px;
}

menu {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand|Raleway|Titillium+Web&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

  <div class="box1">

    <h1>Brixton Sandhals
      <img id="menuleaf" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/microsoft/209/seedling_1f331.png" height="15px"></h1>
    <p><em>"Up here my eyes are green leaves, unseeing."</em></p>
    <br>
    <p>Hello! I am a born and raised Canadian living, working, writing, and musing about a <a class="topics">wide array of topics</a> in Shiga, Japan.</p>
    <div class=menu>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="/quarantine.html">quarantine</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://are.na/brixton-sandhals/">are.na</a></li>
        <li><a href="twitter.com/brixton">twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="instagram.com/ydalir">insta</a></li>
        <li><a href="special.fish/brixton">special.fish</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </div>
  <!---endbox-->
  <div class=box2>✨poetry, bodybuiling, canadian literature, japanese literature, language learning, using linguistics to learn languages, translation as collaboration, techniques for learning chinese, korean, and japanese in tandem, psychoanalysis, religion, the anthropology
    and pyschology of religion, scandinavia, astrology, theopoetics, aesthetics, somaesthetics, hermeneutics, the kyoto school, design, the history of the web, the complex plane, and set theory.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your problem here appears to be that you have not understood how the combinator `+` in a CSS selector works to begin with.

Comment: @mplungjan Hi! Thank you for your response! I've had a look at the examples in the link you've provided. That is where I found the "+" CSS to begin with! Although I am sort of failing to see where my code deviates from the examples from previous answers. Sorry, just a beginner still :)

Comment: @CBroe Hi! Am I trying to use the + for a problem it can't solve? Or am I implementing it incorrectly? Thank you for reaching out!

Comment: What you want can not be achieved with the HTML structure you currently have. `+` selects elements based on that they are _siblings_ of each other, and that is not the case here.

Comment: Where is the `hover + .box` in the example I made a snippet for?

Comment: @mplungjan This part here ```.topics:hover+.box2 {
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: @CBroe Indeed I do not even know what a sibling is haha! This may be a good place for me to start. :.)

Answer (score 0):

I would use script:

NOTE: `<a data-target="quarentine" href="/quarantine.html">quarantine</a>`

```js
const hover = function(tgt,over) {
  if (tgt.tagName.toUpperCase() === "A") {
    const id = tgt.getAttribute("data-target");
    if (id) {
     const div = document.getElementById(id);
     if (div) div.classList.toggle("show",over)
    }
  }
};


document.querySelector(".menu")
  .addEventListener("mouseover",function(e) { hover(e.target,true) })
document.querySelector(".menu")  
  .addEventListener("mouseout",function(e) { hover(e.target) })  

<!---GRAIN JAVA START--->

var viewWidth,
  viewHeight,
  canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"),
  ctx;

// change these settings
var patternSize = 64,
  patternScaleX = 1,
  patternScaleY = 1,
  patternRefreshInterval = 4,
  patternAlpha = 25; // int between 0 and 255,

var patternPixelDataLength = patternSize * patternSize * 4,
  patternCanvas,
  patternCtx,
  patternData,
  frame = 0;

window.onload = function() {
  initCanvas();
  initGrain();
  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
};

// create a canvas which will render the grain
function initCanvas() {
  viewWidth = canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
  viewHeight = canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.scale(patternScaleX, patternScaleY);
}

// create a canvas which will be used as a pattern
function initGrain() {
  patternCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  patternCanvas.width = patternSize;
  patternCanvas.height = patternSize;
  patternCtx = patternCanvas.getContext('2d');
  patternData = patternCtx.createImageData(patternSize, patternSize);
}

// put a random shade of gray into every pixel of the pattern
function update() {
  var value;

  for (var i = 0; i < patternPixelDataLength; i += 4) {
    value = (Math.random() * 255) | 0;

    patternData.data[i] = value;
    patternData.data[i + 1] = value;
    patternData.data[i + 2] = value;
    patternData.data[i + 3] = patternAlpha;
  }

  patternCtx.putImageData(patternData, 0, 0);
}

// fill the canvas using the pattern
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);

  ctx.fillStyle = ctx.createPattern(patternCanvas, 'repeat');
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight);
}

function loop() {
  if (++frame % patternRefreshInterval === 0) {
    update();
    draw();
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(loop);
}

<!---GRAIN JAVA END--->



<!---LEAF JAVA START--->

let leaf = false;

const leaf_animation = () => {
  if (!leaf) {
    document.querySelector(".scale-in-hor-left").style.display = "block";
    leaf = true;
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".scale-in-hor-left").style.display = "none";
    leaf = false;
  }
}

document.querySelector("#menuleaf").addEventListener("click", leaf_animation);

<!---LEAF JAVA END--->
```

```css
body {
  background-size: 70px 70px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, grey 1px, transparent 1px), linear-gradient(to bottom, grey 1px, transparent 1px);
  font-family: Quicksand;
}

#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 80%;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Quicksand;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

p {
  font-color: grey;
  font-size: 11pt;
  margin: 0px;
}

.box1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: static;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  width: 399px;
  height: 280px;
  margin-left: 62px;
  margin-top: 62px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background: white;
}

.box2 {
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: static;
  float: left;
  color: black;
  font-size: 9pt;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: grey;
  width: 331px;
  height: 121px;
  margin-left: 69px;
  margin-top: 132px;
  padding: 9px;
  background: white;
}

.topics:hover+.box2 {
  display: flex;
}

#menuleaf {
  cursor: help;
}

#menuleaf:hover,
#menuleaf:focus {
  margin-left: 2.5px;
}

menu {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-size: 10pt;
}

a:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}
.show { display: flex }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand|Raleway|Titillium+Web&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

  <div class="box1">

    <h1>Brixton Sandhals
      <img id="menuleaf" src="https://emojipedia-us.s3.dualstack.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/thumbs/120/microsoft/209/seedling_1f331.png" height="15px"></h1>
    <p><em>"Up here my eyes are green leaves, unseeing."</em></p>
    <br>
    <p>Hello! I am a born and raised Canadian living, working, writing, and musing about a <a class="topics">wide array of topics</a> in Shiga, Japan.</p>
    <div class=menu>
      <ul>
        <li><a data-target="quarentine" href="/quarantine.html">quarantine</a></li>
        <li><a data-target="arena" href="http://are.na/brixton-sandhals/">are.na</a></li>
        <li><a href="twitter.com/brixton">twitter</a></li>
        <li><a href="instagram.com/ydalir">insta</a></li>
        <li><a href="special.fish/brixton">special.fish</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </div>
  <!---endbox-->
  <div id="quarentine" class=box2>✨poetry, bodybuiling, canadian literature, japanese literature, language learning, using linguistics to learn languages, translation as collaboration, techniques for learning chinese, korean, and japanese in tandem, psychoanalysis, religion, the anthropology
    and pyschology of religion, scandinavia, astrology, theopoetics, aesthetics, somaesthetics, hermeneutics, the kyoto school, design, the history of the web, the complex plane, and set theory.
  </div>
  <div id="arena" class=box2>bla bla bla</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I've tried implementing this code on the part of the site I wanted to, but hit another wall unfortunately. If I want to use this for multiple elements, will it still work if I just add other targets?

Comment: Currently trying to make it work for ```<a data-target="topics">wide array of topics</a>```

Comment: Yes - just add targets and give the div an ID